# Less ad-hoc method of finding number of roots of $p(z)=z^4+3z^2+z+1$ in the right half-plane (Rouché's theorem?)

Tags: complex-analysis

I am doing a problem from a past qualifying exam that asks to find the number of roots of $p(z) = z^4+3z^2+z+1$ in the open right half-plane.

I solved it as follows:

If we factor $p(z) = (z-\zeta_1)(z-\zeta_2)(z-\zeta_3)(z-\zeta_4)$ where each $\zeta_i$ is a root of $p$, then comparing coefficients of the $z^3$ term gives $\zeta_1+\zeta_2+\zeta_3+\zeta_4 = 0$. As such, $p$ cannot have $0$ or $4$ roots on the open right half-plane because otherwise all of them would have a negative or positive real part, respectively. Since $p(z)$ is real on the real axis, by the reflection principle, we have $p(\overline{z}) = \overline{p(z)}$ for all values of $z\in\mathbb C$. Since $p(z)$ has no real roots, it follows that $p(z)$ has an even amount of roots on the right half-plane, which must be $2$ by my statements earlier.

I don't like my answer because it doesn't use any of the complex analysis I learned over the summer and instead appeals to basic principles. My answer is very lucky; it only works because $\deg(p) = 4$, the coefficient of $z^3$ is zero, and $p(z)$ has no real roots.

So, my question is: Is there a more standard way to do this problem so that I can attack similar problems? I wanted to use Rouché's theorem initially but got stuck trying to find $f$ and $g$ to compare. The problem I ran into was that any $f$ or $g$ that I used had zeros on the imaginary axis which spelled doom for my semicircular contour. Thank you for any help!

Comment: A method that you can turn into an algorithm is using the argument principle, for example on a large semi-circle closed with a diameter on the imaginary axis. The number of zeros is the number of times the image of this path winds around the origin. The image of the semi-circle is easy to control, since the leading term is much larger than all others, for large enough radius. On the imaginary axis the real and imaginary parts are polynomials. The signs of polynomials can be determined (roots can be isolated algorithmically). ...

Comment: ... So, you can determine in which quadrant the image image of the segment on the imaginary axis is and with this how many times it winds around $0$.